# Development GAE and PIL usage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library

I've looked thru a number of similar questions there, but none of them helped.
I use Win 7, Python 2.5 and installed PIL 1.1.6 at `d:\Work\Python25\Lib\site-packages\PIL\` (I had PIL 1.1.7 installed before, but the problem was the same).
If I run `python.exe` directly and try to `import Image`, `import PIL` there, then it works well. If I try to do:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
```

directly from my GAE/python code, I get the error:

> No module named PIL

The similar error if I try just `import Image`.

What else should I verify?

Comment: Have you configured libraries in app.yaml as per the docs ?  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Configuring_libraries

Comment: @TimHoffman, this is for Python 2.7 only

Comment: You can't use PIL directly in python 2.5. The SDK uses it as a replacement for the appengine images API.

Comment: @Greg, thanks. Looks like you are right :(. Could you please post your answer as 'answer', so I'll accept it?

Comment: To be honest, hadn't noticed the 2.5 use - you really should move to 2.7 ;-)

Comment: It's more than "should". The 2.5 runtime is deprecated and you must not rely on it.